# General solution of $u_t + u_x = -u^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, nonlinear-dynamics

Can someone help me to write down a formula for the general solution to the nonlinear partial differential equation $$u_t + u_x + u^2 = 0$$ and how do I show that if the initial data is positive and bounded, $0 ≤ u(0,x) = f(x) ≤ M$, then the solution exists for all $t > 0$, and $u(t,x) → 0$ as $t → ∞$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get to solve 
$$
\frac{dt}1=\frac{dx}1=-\frac{du}{u^2}
$$
leading to $$x-t=c_1, ~~u^{-1}-t=c_2$$ along the characteristic curves. As the characteristic curves inside the solution surface form a one-parameter family, there is a function $c_2=\phi(c_1)$ connecting the integration constants, thus
$$
u(t,x)=\frac1{t+\phi(x-t)}.
$$ 
Now apply all the other assumptions and try to prove the claims.

As $f(x)=u(0,x)=\frac{1}{\phi(t)}$, the solution can be rewritten as
$$
u(t,x)=\frac{f(x-t)}{1+t\,f(x-t)}.
$$

If $f(x_*)<0$ at some point, then select $t_*=-\frac1{f(x_*)}$ and consider the point $(t,x)=(t_*, x_*+t_*)$. The denominator will be zero, there will be a singularity at that point.

Comment: thank you, I will take a close look at it.

Comment: If the initial data is negative at some $x$, then the solution blows up at $x$ in ﬁnite time: 

$lim_ {t→τ−}$ $u(t,x)$ $→$ $−∞$ for some $τ$ $>$ $0$ and find a formula for the earliest blow-up time $τ_*$ $>$ $0$.

Comment: You just need to contemplate how to get $t_*$ as small as possible.

Comment: Ok, I shall try that.

Comment: I tried to find the answer, but I am stuck... Are you able to help me?

Comment: You need to take the minimum of $f$, which is negative if there are any negative values. That is, the negative function value with the largest absolute value. $t_*=-1/\inf_{x\in \Bbb R}f(x)$.